# Tell torquebox archive to include certain files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, torquebox

I'm trying to deploy my rails app via torquebox. The app depends on some c libraries which are in a subfolder of /lib with the ending .bin

Sadly, when creating a .knob archive for deployment, these files are not added to it.

How can I configure torquebox so it adds these files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was a bug in the torquebox gem not handling paths with spaces very well. Fixed in newer releases.